# Radio button saving value of fist clicked, not changing to value of second/last clicked

Tags: javascript, radio-button, radio-group, legacy-code

I am working on some legacy code. There is a set of radio buttons, true and false. True comes pre-selected. When I click false, then go back to click true the value being saved is false. How do I re-write this code to make it pull in the value of the LAST clicked radio button?

HTML

```
<label class="input-radio">
   <input name="radio" value="true" type="radio" checked  />
      <span>True</span>
</label>
<label class="input-radio">
   <input name="radio" value="false" type="radio" />
     <span>False</span>
</label>
```

Javascript

```
$('input[name="radio"]').change(function(){
 var selectedValue = $('input[name="radio"]:checked').val();
 if($(this).prop('checked')) {
   $('input[name="radio"]').prop('value',selectedValue);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `value` of the selected radio button to the previously selected radio buttons value. This line of code:

```
$('input[name="radio"]').prop('value',selectedValue);
```

Is causing you to have two radio buttons with the same value. So, you're initial value is true. When you then click `false`, it sets the value of each radio button to false, so when you go back to click `true`, it is in fact set to `false` due to the previous `change`.

I don't know the purpose of this line, but removing it should solve this issue.